# Find objects with attribute containing a certain word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Let's say we have a `User` model with an email attribute.

I would like to do a search and find all users that have the letters "gmail" somewhere in the `email` attribute.

How would I do this in the most recent Rails application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
User.where('email like ?', '%gmail%')
```